# Where do I add permissive flag

Tags: c++, makefile

I am using gcc 4.7 to compile a project on ubuntu 12, it complaint about some errors, which is just saying that standard interior lookup engine was unable to find function or structure.

I need to add -fpermissive flag to eliminate it, where do I add the flag in the Makefile CFLAGS?

A appended to CFLAGS, but it says: 
cc1: error: command line option â-fpermissiveâ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]

I didn't see Werror in the Makefile, could they both exist or only one flag?

Comment: Try `CXXFLAGS`. That is the flag used by default for C++.

Comment: In general, you should *not* use `-fpermissive` unless you know what you are doing (and if you don't know where to add it, you probably don't know what you are doing...).